# java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jsf-2, oracle11g, xhtml

I am getting java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2 error when trying to access a stored proc(created in oracle) which is having client name (varchar) as input param & cursor as output param. The error is coming when i test it thru a JSP page but when I tested the stroed proc thru a Junit i am not getting the error. So I am quite confused. Please find below my stored proc & also the DAOImpl class which is having the call. I can see that the JSP page is properly passing the name from a input text box to the name input param of stored proc.

```
PROCEDURE sp_get_client_details_by_name (
  p_client_name   IN     ncr.ncr_parties.full_legal_name%TYPE,
  p_result_set       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_result_set FOR
     SELECT np.newedge_party_id AS client_id,
            np.full_legal_name AS client_name,
            np.city,
            nc.name residence_country_name,
            np.life_cycle_status AS status,
            ec_addr.addr2 AS client_address1,
            ec_addr.title_dist_compl AS client_address2,
            ec_addr.zip AS client_address3,
            ec_addr.state AS client_address4,
            ec_addr.title_compl AS client_address_tc,
            ec_addr.locality_compl AS client_address_lc,
            le.newedge_legal_entity_id AS legal_entity_id,
            le.full_legal_name AS legal_entity_name,
            le_addr.addr2 AS legal_entity_address1,
            le_addr.title_dist_compl AS legal_entity_address2,
            le_addr.zip AS legal_entity_address3,
            le_addr.state AS legal_entity_address4,
            le_addr.title_compl AS legal_entity_address_tc,
            le_addr.locality_compl AS legal_entity_address_lc
       FROM ncr.ncr_parties np
            JOIN ncr_legal_entities le
               ON np.legal_entity_key = le.legal_entity_key
            JOIN ncrglobalcountryview_vw nc
               ON nc.country_alias_key = np.residence_country_aliases_key
            JOIN ncr_cpty_addresses ec_addr
               ON     ec_addr.cpty_key = np.party_key
                  AND ec_addr.cpty_level = 'P'
                  AND ec_addr.addr_type_key = 1
            JOIN ncr_cpty_addresses le_addr
               ON     le_addr.cpty_key = le.legal_entity_key
                  AND le_addr.cpty_level = 'LE'
                  AND le_addr.addr_type_key = 1
      WHERE np.full_legal_name LIKE '%' || p_client_name || '%';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
        SQLERRM || ' backtrace: ' || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);
     raise_application_error (
        '-20000',
        'Unknown exception occurred. Please contact support.' || SQLERRM);
END sp_get_client_details_by_name;
END pkg_ocr_gui;

public class ECIDDetailsDAOImpl implements ECIDDetailsDAO {

private DataSource dataSource;
private static final String SP_GET_ECID_DETAILS = "ncr.pkg_ocr_gui.sp_get_client_details_by_name";
private static final String EC_ID_NAME_PARAM = "p_client_name";
private static final String ECID_CUR_TYPES = "p_result_set";

public DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public List<ECIDDetails> getECIDDetails(String elementaryClientName) {

        GetECIDDetailsStoredProcedure getECIDDetailsStoreProc = new GetECIDDetailsStoredProcedure(dataSource, SP_GET_ECID_DETAILS);
        Map<String, Object> resultsMap = getECIDDetailsStoreProc.executeECIDetails(elementaryClientName);
        List<ECIDDetails> ecidDetails = (List<ECIDDetails>) resultsMap.get(ECID_CUR_TYPES);
        return ecidDetails;
}

class GetECIDDetailsStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {


    public GetECIDDetailsStoredProcedure(DataSource dataSource, String sprocName) {
        super(dataSource, sprocName);
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter(EC_ID_NAME_PARAM, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(ECID_CUR_TYPES, OracleTypes.CURSOR, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ECIDDetails>(ECIDDetails.class)));
        compile();
    }

    public Map<String, Object> executeECIDetails(String elementaryClientName) {
        Map <String, Object> inputs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inputs.put(EC_ID_NAME_PARAM, elementaryClientName);
        return super.execute(inputs);
    }

}
```

}

Below is my JUnit test which is giving back proper data

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:test-applicationcontext.xml"})
public class ECIDFetchServiceTest {


@Autowired
ECIDDetailsDAOImpl ecIDDAO;


@Test
public void validategetECIDDetails() {
    List<ECIDDetails> ecidDetails = new ArrayList<ECIDDetails>();
    ecidDetails = ecIDDAO.getECIDDetails("ABN");
    assertNotNull(ecidDetails);
    assertTrue(ecidDetails.size() > 0);
}
```

}

Hi Priyesh,

I am using JSF to create the UI. Please find below the necessary codes.

**JSF Code**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <h:outputLabel value="Elementary Client Name"  />
    <h:inputText value="#{ecIDBean.elementaryClientName}"  />
    <h:commandButton value="Get EC" action="#{ecIDBean.executeEcIDList}">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

**Managed Bean Class**

```
public class ECIDFetchBean {

private String elementaryClientName;
private List<ECIDDetails> ecIDList;
private ECIDFetchService ecIDFetchService;


public ECIDFetchBean() {
    ApplicationContext ctx = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
    ecIDFetchService = (ECIDFetchServiceImpl)ctx.getBean("ecIDFetchService");
}

public String getElementaryClientName() {
    return elementaryClientName;
}
public void setElementaryClientName(String elementaryClientName) {
    this.elementaryClientName = elementaryClientName;
}

public List<ECIDDetails> getEcIDList() {
    return ecIDList;

}
public void setEcIDList(List<ECIDDetails> ecIDList) {
    this.ecIDList = ecIDList;
}

public void executeEcIDList() {

    ecIDList = ecIDFetchService.getECIDDetails(elementaryClientName);

}
```

}

**Service Class**

```
public class ECIDFetchServiceImpl implements ECIDFetchService {


private ECIDDetailsDAO ecidDetailsDAO;



public List<ECIDDetails> getECIDDetails(String elementaryClientName) throws OCRReportingException {

    return ecidDetailsDAO.getECIDDetails(elementaryClientName);
}
```

Hi Priyesh,

JSP is also pointing to same Database. I changed my DAOImpl class to call stored proc using 
SimpleJdbcCall & it's working fine now from both JUnit as well as JSP.

```
public List<ECIDDetails> getECIDDetailsBySimpleJDBCCall(String elementaryClientName){


   SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource);
   simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName("ncr.pkg_ocr_gui").withProcedureName("sp_get_client_details_by_name") 
   .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
   .declareParameters(new SqlParameter(EC_ID_NAME_PARAM, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR),
           new SqlOutParameter(ECID_CUR_TYPES, OracleTypes.CURSOR, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<ECIDDetails>(ECIDDetails.class)));
   MapSqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
   sqlParameterSource.addValue(EC_ID_NAME_PARAM, elementaryClientName);
   Map<String, Object> results = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);
   List<ECIDDetails> ecidDetails = (List<ECIDDetails>) results.get(ECID_CUR_TYPES);
   return ecidDetails;
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code that calls the stored procedure from the jsp?

Comment: Priyesh, Edited my question & provided the UI code. Please have a look.

Comment: Everything looks alright. Make sure you are pointing to the same database in test as well as from the application(via jsp).